# Как сделать быстрый парсинг большого количества сайтов на node.js?

Tags: node.js, axios

Как сделать быстрый парсинг большого количества сайтов?
Пробовал через axios, получаю тело, статус код, но например 500 тысяч сайтов, он проверяет достаточно долго, часов 6-10. Возможно ли сократить это время, если да, то как это сделать и на сколько оно сократится примерно?

Comment: Парсинг идет в один поток?

Comment: 6 часов на 500 тысяч сайтов - это 43 миллисекунды на сайт. Вроде бы не так уж и медленно. До многих сайтов один только пинг будет больше.